# jQuery syntax error - Links does not open

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, syntax-error

As you can see in the jsfiddle, the link does not open if you click on `TEST`. I put in all my CSS and Javascript Code. Must be sth. with jQuery (when I delete the library, it works), but I can't find the mistake, unfortunately.

Can you help me please?

https://jsfiddle.net/mah89451/

Error:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:

Comment: Most of the errors are caused becuase you're using the `https://` version of jsFiddle, yet your references use `http://`, hence security warnings. If you use this link, you don't get those issues: http://jsfiddle.net/mah89451/. That leaves one problem regarding adding an event listener to an element that doesn't exist. That line is `document.getElementById("zeichenanzahl")`. Remove that line, or add the required element to the DOM

Answer (score 0):

Your fiddle will not work as long as there are so much javascript errors (document.getElementById() use without ids in your HTML, etc…) so in all cases, it will be impossible to find which of the errors will lead in your issue.

Comment: I am sorry, as I am new to coding, I did not know. The error I got is: Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: jquery.min.js:2:12719